# XSL Template match and then IF condition on following-sibling

Tags: templates, xslt, position, match

I have the following problem. I need to know whether a condition is met on any of x number of sub-nodes of the same name and do not process the line. I'm parsing an xml to a text file but it could have 2 or 3 same sub-nodes called the same with different value and if one of them meets the condition then process the line.

Here's part of my XML:

```
<home>
    <app>
        <data>
            <rec>
                <rpos>1</rpos>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>HLK-TEST-A</item>
                    <desc>SOMETHING1</desc>
                    <ics>
                        <code>HKU</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-A</citem>
                    </ics>  
                    <ics>
                        <code>HLK</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-A</citem>
                    </ics>
                </itemdef>
            </rec>
            <rec>
                <rpos>2</rpos>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>HLK-TEST-B</item>
                    <desc>Test</desc>
                    <ics>
                        <code>HKU</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-B</citem>
                    </ics>
                </itemdef>
            </rec>
            <rec>
                <rpos>3</rpos>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>HLK-TEST-C</item>
                    <desc>Test3</desc>
                    <ics>
                        <code>HLK</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-C</citem>
                    </ics>
                </itemdef>
            </rec>
            <rec>
                <rpos>4</rpos>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>HLK-TEST-D</item>
                    <desc>SOMETHING4</desc>
                    <ics>
                        <code>HLK</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-D</citem>
                    </ics>  
                    <ics>
                        <code>HKU</code>
                        <bpid></bpid>
                        <citem>TEST-D</citem>
                    </ics>
                </itemdef>
            </rec>
        </data>
    </app>
</home>
```

Basically Records 1,3 and 4 have to process because they have a "code" tag with value of HLK

Here's what I have on my XSLT... although I can manage to get only records 1 and 3... could you help?

XSL:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="home/app/data/rec[itemdef/ics[position() = last()]/code[not(starts-with(.,'HLK'))]]">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="home">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="app"/>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="app">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="app" mode="print">
            <xsl:text>105604|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select='date'/>
            <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select='time'/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="data">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rec"/>
            </xsl:template>

                <xsl:template match="rec">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="itemdef"/>
                </xsl:template>

                    <xsl:template match="itemdef">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::app" mode="print"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select='item'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select='desc'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:text>|&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's my current Output:

```
105604|T|HLK-TEST-A|SOMETHING1|||
105604|T|HLK-TEST-C|Test3|||
```

But should be:

```
105604|T|HLK-TEST-A|SOMETHING1|||
105604|T|HLK-TEST-C|Test3|||
105604|T|HLK-TEST-D|SOMETHING4|||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th `rec` element is being filtered out because the empty template is matching on the `rec` elements who's last `ics` element does not start with "HLK". In your XML the last `ics` element for the 4th `rec` element has a value of "HKU", which does not start with "HLK".

From the example XML it seems like your criteria for the empty template should be to match the `rec` elements that do not have an `itemdef/ics/code` that starts with "HLK", regardless of the `position()` of the `ics` element:

```
<xsl:template match="rec[not(itemdef/ics/code[starts-with(.,'HLK')])]" />
```

Alternatively, you could have the empty template match generically on `rec` elements, and the other one match the `rec` elements that have the "HLK" `code` elements.

```
<xsl:template match="rec" />

<xsl:template match="rec[itemdef/ics/code[starts-with(.,'HLK')]]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="itemdef"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your first suggestion did the trick! I was working for 2 days on this and couldn't realize that I needed the opposite :) Thank you Mads!